# Using % in a cron command

Tags: cron-jobs

Since the `%` has special meaning to cron, how do I use it as part of a command?

I found this page http://www.hcidata.info/crontab.htm, which mentions piping `echo` and `sed` to escape the `%` and then remove the extra `\`, but in my case, the command is `date`, which doesn't accept parameters through STDIN, so this doesn't work:

```
echo '+\%Y' | sed -e 's|\\||g' | date
```

I'm thinking I can create a special date script that will output the date in the format I want, and call that instead, but I'm still wondering if it's possible to do it directly in the cron command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) man page says:

> Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed
>   into newline characters, [...]

so you should be able to just escape the `%` character by prefixing it with a backslash `\`:

```
00 15 * * *  user  date '+\%Y'
```

The `\%` sequence is processed by `cron`, so the shell will see the command `date '+%Y'` which is a correct invocation of `date`.

Comment: Hey, how about that, it works... The page I referenced confused me then.