# Cron job not creating snapshots

Tags: cron, elasticsearch

I have a cron job set up in my crontab which is set to fire a snapshot every first minute of an hour. When I see the cron logs I can see that it triggered the task but I do not see the snapshots in Kibana client. I curl'ed the ElasticSearch instance directly and do not see the snapshots there either.  When I try to run the cron script manually from one of the nodes it works fine and creates a snapshot but surprisingly the crontab job does not do so.

Here is my cron job setting

```
 1 * * * * root curl -v -k -s -X PUT https://<redacteduser>:<reactedpassword>@localhost:9201/_snapshot/s3_backup_repository/%3Csnapshot-%7Bnow%2Fh%7Byyyy.mm.dd-hh%7D%7D%3E?wait_for_completion=true >> /opt/elasticsearch/system/system.log 2>&1
```

This cron job is set on all the three EC2 instances in our ES cluster.

Here is the row in cron log in `/var/log/` which shows the script was triggered per the cron schedule. (I see this in all the 3 EC2 instances in ES Cluster all with the same timestamp).

```
Sep 28 18:01:01 ip-10-7-22-136 CROND[17730]: (root) CMD (curl -v -k -s -X PUT https://redacteduser:redactedpassword@localhost:9201/_snapshot/s3_backup_repository/)
```

The system.log file in all the 3 instances on path `/opt/elasticsearch/system` do not have any trace of the snapshot triggered by the cron tasks.

Any idea why this could be happening? Is it because all the 3 instances in the cluster try to trigger the snapshot all the same time?

Thanks, 
Rahul

Comment: Inside the crontab, try to call curl with full path (something like `/usr/bin/curl`)

Comment: It's likely the `%` characters in the URL - see for example [Using % in a cron command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6444/using-in-a-cron-command)

Comment: @steeldriver that solved the problem. Thanks for catching that.